# Which category of Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, luxembourg

I am from India and am going to Luxembourg to meet a friend who is coming from Seattle. So, even he does not have a permanent address per se. So, is it advisable for me to apply for a tourist visa or a "Visit friend" visa? IT returns are expected for tourist visa and I do not have them yet. (I have been into employment only for 4 months now)

Answer (score 4):

There are no strictly defined “categories” of Schengen visa and you can also always select “other”. It's true that there are some differences in the supporting documentation expected by some consulates depending on the box you check on the form but there is nothing stopping you from including more. The most important thing is to present a coherent story with a credible plan and all relevant information to avoid creating the impression that you are deceptive.

Specifically, having no income tax returns could be a problem in your case. It's sometimes possible to omit them if you are visiting close family, when you can credibly claim that your host will cover the costs of your stay and you have a proper invitation (one that's stamped/validated by the local authorities). But that's apparently not your case so you can't simply claim to be visiting a friend and rely on that to meet the financial means requirement.

Furthermore, documentary evidence of a stable situation are also useful to meet other requirements, which is another reason to provide tax returns even if you check “visit to family and friends” as the purpose of the trip. As @phoog explained, if income tax returns do not show you in a favorable light or you have none at all, you can also provide other things that show you have enough income and reasons to come back to your country of residence.

Comment: How can one include income tax returns if one has never paid income tax ("I do not have them yet")?

Comment: @phoog I misread the question, I assumed the OP did not have “good” income tax returns reflecting the new job (as opposed to one showing no income and 0 tax paid). I will edit the answer but the point is that checking “visit to family and friends” does not really change the requirements.

Comment: @phoog Maybe the answer alse reflects a bit of confusion on my part about the way income tax works in the US and elsewhere but I have some document stating how much tax I owed in each year since I stopped being included on my parents' income tax filings, even in years in which I did not work or paid no income tax.

Comment: I had assumed the OP is not in the US.  But I can say that in the US, for 2014, single people under 65 years old are not required to file if their income is under $10,150.  The IRS will issue a document confirming that someone did not file in a given year; such a certificate would obviously be helpful for the OP's application if he is in fact in the US.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are "visiting" a friend who is also a tourist (perhaps it's better to say you are *meeting* or *traveling with* a friend), you should apply as a tourist.

If you have been employed for only four months, and have no income tax returns, you can still apply.  Just include a letter explaining that you've been employed for this short time and that's why you don't yet have returns.  Show your pay records for the four months instead.

You will probably receive extra scrutiny as an overstay risk, because of the short term of your employment.  Any objective evidence of your intention to keep your current job and return to your home will help (a lease for your apartment, for example).

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to apply for a shot stay visa. this visa will allow you to travel for a maximum of 90 days in every 6 months period. with regards to your income tax, do you have other source of proof of income in form of your payslips and bank statements? if your payslip has details of your PAYE tax then you should be fine as long as there is some substantial amount in your bank statement to cover your trip.