# How difficult is it to get Schengen visa from India?

Tags: schengen, luxembourg

I have been employed for 4 months and I do not have a credit card nor IT returns yet. I'm applying from Luxembourg embassy. My trip is a week long and I have enough cash in my account to cover my expenses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which category of Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59038/which-category-of-schengen-visa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schengen Visa Application: tips for preparing](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing)

Answer (score 1):

Many factors can play a role and it's difficult to predict the outcome. A longer work history/more stable situation would certainly help. [These statistics](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/overview_of_schengen_visa_statistics_en.pdf) are already a few years old but in 2012 the refusal rate for application from India across all Schengen member states was 6.1%, which is not bad compared to some other countries but still means there is a non-negligible chance to be refused a visa.